# Photoshop CS6 displaying incorrect glyphs

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, glyphs

So I've downloaded a google font known as 'Didact Gothic' from [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Didact+Gothic). It works perfectly when embedded in a website. However, Photoshop CS6 does something really odd to the 'w' glyph:

[image: photoshop error]

The .ttf file completely fine:

[image: glyph specimen page]

And it even works in Pages:

[image: Didact Gothic working in pages]

So what on Earth is going on? The rogue 'w' in photoshop appears to be from a different font called Mistral, I think. Bizarre. Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download a different version of the font.

Didact Gothic for example is found here:

http://openfontlibrary.org/en/font/didact-gothic

As are a lot of google fonts.

(This version worked perfectly for *me*, despite Font Book throwing a 'serious' error warning)

[image: fixed]

Answer (score 0):

Un-install, re download a new copy and then install again, make sure Photoshop and any other Adobe application is closed to be on the safe side.

I've seen similar issues before and this has worked for me. If it doesn't you may need to try re-installing Photoshop.

Comment: its not very convenient having to reinstall photoshop every time it doesn't recognize a font, are you sure there isn't any other way

Comment: Did you try removing and getting a new copy of the font first like I said ? If not see what JWH said below

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the version that worked in my case: [Didact Gothic](http://danieljohnson.name/fonts/didact-gothic)

In my case it had to be the OpenType version that worked like a charm. True Type variant mixed up "w".